# Rewrite image path with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have these old site and it has the image url in all of its .htm files like this below,

```
<img border="0" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="xxx" width="170" height="150">
```

I want to know if I can add an **absolute path** before all the image URLs with htaccess.

For instance,

```
<img border="0" src="http://localhost/mysite/local/applications/bin/oldsite/images/logo.jpg" alt="xxx" width="170" height="150">
```

Is it possible?

Or do I have to change the image path manually file by file?

My attempt,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ local/applications/bin/oldsite/images/$1 [QSA,L]
```

not working of course!

Answer (score 0):

Your rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ local/applications/bin/oldsite/images/$1 [QSA,L]
```

would redirect `images/image.jpg` to `local/applications/bin/oldsite/images/images/image.jpg`

Lose the `images/` part from the end of your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ local/applications/bin/oldsite/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i just tested it but still no change... :(

Answer (score 0):

I made it with this rule,

```
RewriteRule ^images\/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))?$ local/applications/bin/oldsite/images/$1 [QSA,L]
```